# Angular - Apollo: Client has not been defined yet

Tags: javascript, angular, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

I'm using apollo client for graphql. I set up the client in AppApolloModule that I'm importing in AppModule. I'm making a query in a service which is also imported right in the AppModule. Although the service runs before the AppApolloModule runs and hence apollo is not initialized when the query is made and I get this error

```
Error: Client has not been defined yet
```

AppApolloModule

```
imports ....

export class AppApolloModule {

    constructor(
        apollo: Apollo,
        httpLink: HttpLink,
        private userService: UserService
    ) {
        console.log("apollo module")
        apollo.create({
            link: httpLink.create({ uri: `${environment.apiBase}/graphql?${this.myService.token}`}),
            cache: new InMemoryCache()
        })
    }

}
```

App Module

```
import { AppApolloModule } from './app.apollo.module';
import { MyService } from './services/my.service';

export class AppModule {
      constructor() {
        console.log("app module")
      }
}
```

I don't get the two consoles app module and apollo module, since the service runs first, it doesn't find any initialized apollo app and thus breaks the code.

How can I make apollo run before the service or any services for that matter in an efficient and standard way?

Comment: Have you tried using app lifecycle OnInit ? try implementing the OnInit interface and bring your code into the ngOnInit method

Comment: Maybe have a look at `APP_INITIALIZER` token

Comment: @e.m.b services don't have ngOnInit

Comment: I meant move the code in the modules constructor to the ngOnInit in the modules not the services

Comment: @e.m.b that won't help either, as contructor function runs first, putting it on ngOnIt will make them load even after more time

Comment: @David I have tried APP_INITIALIZER, but the problem is I have to use myService and if I provide myService, I'm getting a cyclic dependency error

Comment: @ManzurKhan did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: you can initialize Apollo in a new way now
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/setup.html#using-dependency-injection

Answer (score 9):

This will solve the issue nicely:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS} from 'apollo-angular';
import {HttpLink, HttpLinkModule} from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({uri: 'https://api.example.com/graphql'}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule, ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Yay! Much better like this. Too bad the Apollo docs don't put this as the first example.

Comment: Did you just move the instantiation of Apollo inside AppModule?

Comment: After upgrading to Apollo v3 - this approach is giving me the issue again "Client has not been defined yet"

Comment: @DauleDK how did you fixed it ?

Comment: We switched the stack to Svelte/Sapper - we never managed to fix the issue in our team.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue an the docs from Apollo helped me. Go to 'https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/setup/' or copy this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from "apollo-angular";
import { HttpLinkModule, HttpLink } from "apollo-angular-link-http";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ApolloModule,
    HttpLinkModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: (httpLink: HttpLink) => {
      return {
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        link: httpLink.create({
          uri: "https://o5x5jzoo7z.sse.codesandbox.io/graphql"
        })
      }
    },
    deps: [HttpLink]
  }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @wendellmva didn't work for me. What **did** work was the solution suggested in this repo:

https://github.com/patricknazar/angular-lazy-loading-apollo-client

which is basically to put Apollo initialization in a separate, shared module, and include it in your main app module with `forRoot()`.

Comment: This link is no longer available.

Comment: Could you update the link to the repository please?

Comment: @jowey it appears that the owner removed it and unfortunately I didn't think of cloning it at the time. Our setup is a bit more complex now, so I cannot post it here. Perhaps the official documentation has been updated, as raffaval writes below?

Comment: Try this: https://apollo-angular.com/docs/get-started

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deleting the `.angular` folder and serving the application again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked for me with angular +16/17:

**app.config.ts**

```js
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  provideRouter,
  withComponentInputBinding,
  withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation,
  withViewTransitions,
} from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  ApolloClientOptions,
  ApolloLink,
  GraphQLRequest,
  InMemoryCache,
} from '@apollo/client/core';
import { APOLLO_OPTIONS, ApolloModule } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { SECRET, URI, PROPERTY } from './uri-info';

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  const headers = setContext((operation: GraphQLRequest, context) => ({
    headers: {
      [PROPERTY]: SECRET,
    },
  }));
  return {
    link: ApolloLink.from([headers, httpLink.create({ uri: URI })]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      appRoutes,
      withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation(),
      withComponentInputBinding(),
      withViewTransitions(),
    ),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideAnimations(),
    importProvidersFrom(ApolloModule),
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
};
```

**init-graphQl.component.ts**

```js
import { Apollo, gql } from 'apollo-angular';
import { Component, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'test-init-graphql',
  template: `Console log is here`,
})
export class InitGraphQlComponent implements OnInit {
  #apollo = inject(Apollo);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.#apollo
      .watchQuery({
        query: gql`
          {
            Entity {
              firstProperty
              secondProperty
            }
          }
        `,
      })
      .valueChanges.subscribe((result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
 }
```